# How do you extract data from a third party website, such as a price?

Tags: javascript

So lets say I have a product page and I want to be able to dynamically show the price based off of what a major retailer is pricing it as.  For example Amazon.  How could I pull the price from Amazon to show up on my page.  Here is a fiddle below.

Lets say I wanted to pull price data from Amazon here: [http://www.amazon.com/Weedeater-967184101-Straight-Trimmer-W25SBK/dp/B00FMWWQYY/ref=sr_1_1?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1415311397&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FMWWQYY)

Obviously this is crudely done, its only to demonstrate what I mean.

```
<div id="productContainer">
   <div class="products">
       <figure>
           <img src="#" alt="weed eater">
           <figcaption>Excellent Weed Eater Lorem Ipsum content
            <br />
            <p>Cost only<span class="price"></span>
            </p>
        </figcaption>
       </figure>
   </div>
   <div class="products">
       <figure>Other Products etc..</figure>
   </div>
   <div class="products">
       <figure>Other Products etc..</figure>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cL8346k7/

Comment: Or if someone can point me to some resources that will okay too.

Comment: First thing you need to do is to talk to a lawyer so they confirmed it's legal. It's unlikely amazon allows someone to parse their pages for any purpose.

Comment: I'd do all this offline and store it in your own database.  Check out something like Scrapy, which is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: The format of the data you want will surely be different among sites, so you wil have to write a different program for each one. You will also need to change your code whenever the structure in a target site changes. Also it's illegal in most cases. The alternative is using those site's API's when available, which is not a coding nightmare and as a bonus is legal.

Comment: [This might help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_RetrievingPriceInformation.html) for Amazon.  Other sites might have similar APIs.

Comment: BTW, it's perfectly legal.  Prices are *factual information* meaning they're not [subject to copyright](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl102.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use an API exposed by the retailer or scrape their website using a backend language (PHP, Python, Node.js etc. The render the HTML server side with the scraped values inserted or query your own API for the items (that you've scraped) and render them using client-side templates.

This can be non-trivial and unreliable overall.